# Undefined SESSION variable after logout

Tags: session, authentication, logout

I made a login page that lead you to the main page . 
and on the the main page I made this code:

```
 session_start();   
<?php  echo  'welcome, '. $_SESSION['email']; ?>
```

that will welcome anyone that will login in the main page. and if anyone logout from the main page it will lead him also to the main page. just like login and logout from the forums. eveything works fine but the problem is when I log out from the main page or when I am not login I get an error in the main page:

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 25

how can I fix this problem?

this is my logout code:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a simple check to see if the session is set:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['email']) === true){
     // Say "Welcome"
     echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['email'];
  } else {
    // Do nothing, the session is not set
  }
?>
```

EDIT: I have read your comment, and I would recommend the logout.php code to be:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  // Destroy the sessions
  // If you have more sessions, add more like below, but replace email if it is different:
  // unset($_SESSION['session_name']);
  unset($_SESSION['email']);
  session_destroy();

  header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your logout code look like?  Are you using unset($_SESSION) instead of session_destroy?

Comment: I put it in my quistion

Comment: And, the session_start in the index.php is the first thing (or at least before the html tag)?